# show the swt tabs on java file

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, windowbuilder

I'm new to Eclipse and SWT, just found that [WindowBuilder](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/) is a good tool for UI design.

However, when I download the sample Phonebook and opened it, it doesn't show the normal

> Source | Design | Bindings

tabs at the bottom of the file. The file was treated as a normal java file. Is there anything I can do to let them show as they are when I create an SWT designer file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the Java file and choose *Open with...* to select the WindowBuilder editor.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is not appearing in the windowbuilder then there is somehting wrong with the content of file and windowbuilder is unable to parse the file. I would suggest you to create a new file and view in the window builder.